# C++: Arquivo header não reconhecendo classe

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, classes, arquivo-header

Eu estou trabalhando com diversas classes, e para me organizar melhor, coloquei cada classe em um arquivo diferente.

actor.h

```
#ifndef ACTOR_H
#define ACTOR_H

#include "SDL.h"
#include <string>

#include "collision.h"
#include "world.h"

class Actor
{
    (...)
};
```

world.h

```
#ifndef WORLD_H
#define WORLD_H

#include "actor.h"

class World
{
public:
    (...)
    Actor* getActor(std::string id); //Erro aqui
    (...)
};
```

Porém estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

```
C:\Users\Felipe\Desktop\Joguinho v2\source\world.h|38|error: 'Actor' does not name a type|
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia do motivo do erro?

Comment: `Actor` e `World` precisam se enxergar mutuamente? Só estou vendo dependência de `World.getActor`

Comment: Sim. Há varias funções em Actor que utilizam getters e setters da classe World

Comment: adaptei minha resposta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em `C` tem um conceito chamado `forward declaration`. Eu conheço esse conceito para funções, onde eu posso declarar a existência da função para, somente em um momento posterior, explicar como é a implementação.

Em `C++`, esse conceito se aplica a classes também. [Essa resposta no Stack Overflow internacional](https://stackoverflow.com/a/628079) trata justamente do seu problema (dependência cíclica entre classes) usando a declaração de classes como `forward declaration`. A resposta original também fornece muitos detalhes interessantes de como funciona o compilador, vou resumir aqui o como evitar esses problemas de um jeito pragmático.

Para poder referenciar uma classe (como ponteiro ou referência), é necessário que ela seja declarada antes. Para o seu caso de atores em um mundo, podemos colocar as classes desse nível semântico nos mesmos arquivos header e de código.

Para usar desse jeito, faça assim no header:

```
#ifndef WORLD_ACTORS_H
#define WORLD_ACTORS_H

class Actor; // apenas a forward declaration, sem implementação 
class World; // idem

// real código relativo à classe Actor 
class Actor {
    ...
}

class World {
    Actor* getActor(std::string id);
    ...
}
```

No arquivo de código, basta incluir o header descrito acima e ser feliz.

Se você quiser continuar usando as classes em arquivos distintos (o que é justo), você precisa declarar no header de World a classe Actor (com `forward declaration`); como Actor depende de World, também faça a `forward declaration` da classe World.

Answer (score 1):

Comece por aqui: coloque ponto e vírgula após a declaração da classe...todas as declarações de classe precisam de um ponto e vírgula no final.

```
class Actor
{
   (...)
}; //<------------------------------------
```

Edição:

Ok, já que as vírgulas foram acertadas então agora você pode aceitar a resposta colocada pelo "@Jefferson Quesado" e usar forward declarations, porque o erro está sendo causado por includes recursivos:

actor.h

```
#include "world.h" // <---------------------------------
```

world.h

```
#include "actor.h" // <------------------------
```

Comment: Post editado. Eu esqueci de coloca-las aqui no post, mas meu código possui. Não é este o erreo